# AngularJS - http.get(...).than is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with my code, I'm getting this error when trying to work with $http. Anyone had a problem like this in the past?

```
angular.js:14794 TypeError: http.get(...).than is not a function
at new <anonymous> ((index):57)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5112)
at angular.js:11083
at Object.link (angular-route.js:1209)
at angular.js:1383
at wa (angular.js:10611)
at q (angular.js:10000)
at f (angular.js:9240)
at angular.js:9105
at angular.js:9496 "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"
```

this is my code

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#/!" class="brand-logo right">Logo</a>
            <ul class="left">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#/!">CD</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!dvd">DVD</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!dvddl">DVD-DL</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view></div>   
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("diskManagment", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when("/", {
                    templateUrl: "discs.htm",
                    controller: "cd"
                })
                .when("/dvd", {
                    templateUrl: "discs.htm",
                    controller: "dvd"
                })
                .when("/dvddl", {
                    templateUrl: "discs.htm",
                    controller: "dvddl"
                });
        });

        app.controller("cd", ['$scope', '$http', function(scope, http) {
            http.get("discs.php?type=cd")
                .than(function (response) {
                    scope.discs = response.data.discs;
                });
        }]);

        app.controller("dvd", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("discs.php?type=dvd")
                    .than(function (response) {
                        scope.discs = response.data.discs;
                    });
            }]);

        app.controller("dvddl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("discs.php?type=dvddl")
                    .than(function (response) {
                        scope.discs = response.data.discs;
                    });
            }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

I cant seem to find out what causing the problem, I tried every way I found that was supposed to work

I can really use some help, thanks!

Comment: `.than()` should be `.then()` ...

Comment: I think the function you are looking for is `then`

Comment: I am so stupid, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaked when wrote .than instead of .then